# Can some one tell me how am I getting this plot wrong?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot 2 columns from a CSV file. Using 'matplotlib' only. I have 4 columns namely the `duration`, `day_of_week`, `month`, `user_type`.

I want to plot duration on the y-axis and either `day_of_week` or month on the x-axis.

```
def change_month(filename):
    with open(data_file3, 'r') as f_in:
        # set up csv reader object
        reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)
        data1 = []
        data2 = []
        data3 = []
        for row in reader:
            data1.append(str(row['day_of_week']))
            data2.append(float(row['duration']))

        return data1, data2

data1, data2 = change_month(data_file1)
plt.bar(data1, data2, 0.8)
plt.show()
```

This is the graph I am getting, but the values on y axis are too small. They should be atleast in the range 2k to 10k

[image]

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong? We can't say much without knowing the data files. When you print out data1, data2 prior to plotting - does it meet your expectations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, looking at your plot, that you are confused while the days are not in order. The reason for this is that you read the csv file using `DictReader`. Dictionaries do not keep the orders of the entries. If you want to preserve the order of the `rows`, you need to read out the file as a list. Example:

```
import csv
import numpy as np 

def change_month(filename):
    with open(data_file3, 'r') as f_in:

        # set up csv reader object
        reader = csv.reader(f_in)
        data1 = []
        data2 = []

        for i,row in reader:

            # Assuming that first row is the header
            if i==0:
                data1.append(row)

            # Assuming that all following rows contain data 
            else:
                data2.append(row)

        # Convert data to float
        data2=np.array(data2).astype(float)

        return data1, data2

data1, data2 = change_month(data_file1)
plt.bar(data1, data2, 0.8)
plt.show()
```

Hope that works for you.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question; which isn't really your fault, because the question itself is sufficiently unclear as it is missing the data in use ([mcve]). In such cases it would probably make more sense to leave a comment asking for clarification than providing an answer, which does not solve the problem.

Comment: Sure, it just seemed that this is the only "wrong" thing with the plot. And the dictionary sorting is a common pitfall. Let's see if @Chaitanya Srikar actually meant this problem or respecifies his question. Otherwise I can delete my answer any time.

Comment: Ok I am sorry for not being clear. The CSV file contains 276799 lines. The duration ranges from few minutes to an hour. And everything is in minutes. If i plot the graph each day should have atleast tens of thousands on y axis but here it is only upto 1400.

Comment: What does ``np.shape(data1)`` and ``np.shape(data2)`` tell you?